# JavaScript: how to access the textbox in the second row of the table

Tags: javascript

I have an html code like this -

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="99%" id="subAccTable">
        <tr>
               <h2>Sub Accounts</h2>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>action </th>
            <th>account</th>
            <th>homeDir</th>
            <th>primaryGroup</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="vtierId" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subAcc"
                value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subHomeDir"
                value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subPriGroup"
                value=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to fill the values of textboxes named subAcc, subHomeDir, subPriGroup using javascript. How can i do it ?

Comment: What've you tried? What have you researched, and what went wrong? Fill the values with what? In response to what action(s)?

Comment: I have an array called obj which contains values . I have to fill the values in this array to the textboxes in my table rows .

Comment: hi TJHeuvel ! I want to do it using the table node and not with any other thing as i am also doing cloning of the same table.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to get the proper DOMElement; including:

- Giving each element an id and getting it using `document.getElementById`
- Using `document.getElementsByName`. This is not preferred since there can be multiple elements with the same name, however there can be only one with the same id.
- Using the form directly. For example if your form's name is form1: `form1.subAcc`
- Using `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and then getting the proper index.

I'd recommend using the id to retrieve the proper element.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to give these textboxes a unique id, then reference them like this:

```
<input type="text" id="subHomeDir" name="subHomeDir" value=""/>

var tb = document.getElementById("subHomeDir");
tb.value = "foo";
```

---

If you're stuck with the names only, then you can use `document.getElementsByName`, just remember, this will return a **collection** of elements (since names are not necessarily unique), which you'll have to index:

```
var tb = document.getElementsByName("subHomeDir")[0];
tb.value = "foo";
```